# PHP: looking for something like Java Stream API

Tags: php, lambda, map-function

Is there a way to convert array of **objects** into an **array  of strings** using some custom mapping in PHP. Like:

```
$objs = array(o1, o2, o3);

...

$strings = conv($objs, function($o) -> $o->fieldXYZ);
```

instead of:

```
$objs = array(o1, o2, o3);

...

$strings = array();

foreach($objs as $obj) {
    $strings []= $obj->fieldXYZ;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function. For example, this should work:

```
$strings = array_map(function($o) {
    return $o->fieldXYZ;
}, $objs);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Tnx.

Comment: It is **not a general lambda solution**, you can't use associative array. See also [this question with the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29213170/287948).